# How to check if any element of list starts with any character from given range?

Tags: scala

I've got a list of names and given range of characters A..F
I've tried this:

```
val r = x.filter(_.name.startsWith('A' to 'F'))
```

but it doesn't work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 1st character test is always a range, and not a collection of discreet characters, you can filter on the ASCII value.

```
val r = x.filter(y => y.name.head >= 'A' && y.name.head <= 'F')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `listOfExpectedChars.contains(firstLetter)`.

```
scala> val names = Seq("Architects", "Metallica", "Pink floyd", "Foo Fighters")
names: Seq[String] = List(Architects, Metallica, Pink floyd, Foo Fighters)

scala> names.filter(name => ('A' to 'F').contains(name(0)))
res1: Seq[String] = List(Architects, Foo Fighters)
```

`name(0)` is equivalent to `name.head`.

```
scala> names.filter(name => ('A' to 'F').contains(name.head))
res2: Seq[String] = List(Architects, Foo Fighters)
```

Note that `.head` on empty array errors out `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. So safer way is to use `.headOption`

```
scala> val names = Seq("Architects", "Metallica", "Pink floyd", "Foo Fighters", "")
names: Seq[String] = List(Architects, Metallica, Pink floyd, Foo Fighters, "")

scala> names.filter(name => ('A' to 'F').map(Option(_)).contains(name.headOption))
res3: Seq[String] = List(Architects, Foo Fighters)
```

Comment: It works! but what happens if I get rid of toList after range? Isn't it redundant?

Answer (score 0):

"There exists a name from list 1 such that there exists a letter from list 2 such that the head of the name is the letter":

`list1.exists(name => list2.exists(letter => name.headOption == Some(letter)))`

Examples:

```
scala> List("Alice", "Bob").exists(name => ('A' to 'F').exists(letter => name.headOption == Some(letter)))
res1: Boolean = true

scala> List("Alice", "Bob").exists(name => ('X' to 'Z').exists(letter => name.headOption == Some(letter)))
res2: Boolean = false
```